# Display a message before "save as" dialog pop-up

Tags: javascript, web, vbscript, asp-classic

I've a classic asp page that consults a webservice and generate data to the client. After the data is loaded it should pop up a "save as" browser dialog, so the client can save the file in .doc.

I've done this. My problem began when I was asked to put a message before the "save as dialog" pop-up. Here is my code:

```
'*********************
'* Get the webservice content
'*********************
Dim oHTTP : Set oHTTP = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
oHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
oHTTP.Send
If 200 = oHTTP.Status Then
   HTML = oHTTP.responseText
Else
   ' handle error
End If

'*********************
'* Write the content in a .doc
'*********************
Response.Write(HTML)

'***********************
'* Open "Save as" dialog
'***********************
Response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown"
FileName = "*.doc"
Response.Addheader "Content-Disposition", _
    "attachment; filename=" & chr(34) & FileName & chr(34)
%>


<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     alert("Loading Webservice data...")
 </script>
</head>
</html>
```

For some reason the "open save as dialog" code is swallowing the javascript making it to not execute.

If I comment the "open save as dialog" lines and run the code, the javascript will work, but when the code is activated it won't display the message.

I think the asnwer is simple but I'm not a classic ASP developer so I'm a bit lost.

So my question is:

How can I display a loading message before I pop-up the "save as dialog"?

Comment: Use a `<div>` rather then an `alert()` to show loading message.

Comment: I've tried it and "save as" keeps swallowing the javascript code. The client must see the pop-up window so I just can't change the alert() for a div, but thanks for the suggestion. I've tried changing the javascript place, put the vbscript inside of the html, tried html events but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Sorry that won't work because your trying to do it all from one page. You will need to break up the loading and the document retrieval into two separate pages or retrieve the document via an ajax call.

Comment: I think I just can't separate it in two pages, my boss won't accept it. I'm having a hard time with ajax (never used it before), from your suggestion I got the idea to do the document processing with ajax store the value in the page session and make the asp page recover it and show the "save as" dialog with the right values, but I don't know if this would work.

Comment: I've given up, the client wants this for today and I'm trying to solve it since yesterday afternoon so i've run out of time. Hopefully this was just an extra thing so it will not have a huge impact on the client. **Lankymart** thanks for the help, if you want to post your suggestion as an answer I would appreciate it.

Comment: The fundmental issue is your trying to respond as a document but still behave like an HTML page. Quick fix would be to call your document download code as a hyperlink and use an `onclick` event to display your disclaimer then `return true;` to let the hyperlink fire and download your document.